# CORS policy errors

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an .Net Core API running on https://localhost:44371 and a Blazor app running on https://localhost:44346.  As you can see they aren't running on the same port, so I'm getting a CORs error of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.  These are new projects generated through Visual Studio.

1. Can I have them both run from the same port?
2. If so how can I dictate which port to use?
3. Will making them run from the same port fix this problem?
4. If not, what's a work around?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: If you research what CORS is, you'll have the answer to all of these questions, and you'll also learn how to resolve this without needing to have them on the same port. I know that's disappointing to hear,  but if you're writing a modern web app you need to have a solid understanding of the CORS fundamentals. [MDN is great place to start for web technology documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: :-)I appreciate your honesty!

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot run two separated app at the same port.

and also, same port wont fix your issue.

You should enable the CORS middleware in asp.net core. try enable it using docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0

and also be aware that you should have a exception handler because any unhandled exception will clear CORS headers.

you can use this doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0